# How to clear datagridview using timer?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to update datagridview every 10 seconds. So far after update, new rows are added and I want to clean the datagridview before update.

The problem is that, when I call inside of `OnCallBack()` `dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();` and `dataGridView2.Refresh();`, I get an exception:

> Cross-thread operation not valid

I have tried to Invoke it, but it doesn't help.

```
 if(dataGridView2.InvokeRequired){
        dataGridView2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate{
        dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView2.Refresh();
 }));
```

My code:

```
    private void Live(){
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer (_ => OnCallBack(), null, 1000,Timeout.Infinite); 
    }

    private void OnCallBack()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
        counter--;

        label8.Text = counter.ToString();          
        if (counter == 0){
                string[] pr = {"124"};
                search.SearchLive(pr, dataGridView2, label10);
                counter = 10;
        }
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer (_ => OnCallBack(), null, 1000,Timeout.Infinite);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Timers class to create a new timer along with its interval

```
 System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
 timer1.Interval = 1000; //time after which you want to clear datagrid
 timer1.Start();
 timer1.Elapsed += TimerTick;
```

Then create an event handler for TimerTick

```
private void TimerTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   if (dataGridView1.rows.count>0)
   {
     dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
     dataGridView1.Refresh();
   }
}
```

Add this check if you want to prevent further crossthreading exceptions

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only access UI components from the UI thread. The `Threading.Timer` will execute the callback on a thread from the thread pool, and not the UI thread, causing your exception.But there are ways to dispatch your function call to the UI thread.

## Dispatch your call to the UI thread

Most UI frameworks are completely single threaded. It is not allowed to access any component from a different thread than the UI thread.

You need to dispatch to the current UI thread. Looking it at your control names, it looks either like a WinForms or a WPF application.

In WinForms you need the following code to dispatch back to the UI thread:

```
public void UpdateUI(object parameter)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => UpdateUI(parameter)));
        return;
    }

    // Update or access here 
}
```

In WPF the following snipped allows you to change the ui form a different thread:

```
public void UpdateUI(object parameter)
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => UpdateUI(parameter)));
       return;
    }

    // Do update or access here
}
```

The important thing to notice here, is that those functions will be executed on the UI thread and not on the calling thread.

Edit: the object parameter is completely optional. It was intended as a example of how to use this method with a function with parameters.

## Using System.Timers.Timer

You could also use the `System.Timers.Timer`, which works quite similiar to the timer in `System.Threading.Timer` but will execute the callback on the UI thread.